# How to get item by key in dynamodb using AWS SDK v2?

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go, amazon-dynamodb

I am learning Golang to connect dynamodb using AWS-SDK-GO-V2 but I do not understand how to get one item by key.

All example that i saw it is using the v1 but I NEED WITH V2.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/mtke80/how_to_get_item_by_key_using_aws_sdk_v2/gv1ukde/?context=3)

Example

```
getItemInput := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
  Key: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
    "Id": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: id},
  },
  TableName:            aws.String("TableName"),
  ConsistentRead:       aws.Bool(true),
  ProjectionExpression: aws.String("Id, Name, Timestamp"),
}
```

Answer (score -7):

AWS SDK Go V2 Developer guide is a good place to start.

Recommend taking a look at https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/getting-started/

Comment: The link provided links to generic skk v2 docs.  Those docs do not contain any specific detail about how to resolve the OPs question.